# How to make a public server through docker

Tags: docker, server

So I have started learning docker, and where better to start than with servers! Anyways, I started out trying to create a minecraft server. I managed to get it working on localhost, but is there any way to make it available to people outside of my own wifi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better get an EC2 instance (VPS) from AWS or any cloud provider and run your docker image in it.

The server will be available 24/7 and you keep your machine safe, it's bad to open ports on your computer for the external world.

*You can get a free instance on AWS for one year*

Comment: Thanks. Is it bad to run a server locally without the cloud, even if it is in a docker container?

Comment: You can do it, just make sure you don't mess with your firewalls and open ports to keep everything safe